# Tests fail to run on React Native

Tags: react-native, jestjs

My `babel.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'
  ]
};
```

When I run `npm test` I get:

> **Test suite failed to run**
>
> **[BABEL] unknown: Preset /* your preset */ requires a filename to be set when babel is called directly,***
>   **babel.transform(code, { filename: 'file.ts', presets: [/ your preset** */] });
>
> See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#filename for more information.

If I change config file to:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'react-native'
  ]
}
```

then all tests run. 
My question: can I change it? What is the difference between both?

Thank you!

Comment: What is babel and react-native version you are using?

Comment: @ofer2980 did you have `metro-react-native-babel-preset` module installed in `node_modules` folder when trying to run `npm test`?

Comment: what is your `package.json` / `jest.config.js` looking like